# SAX Parser in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, sax

I am getting following error when i parse my XML

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
04-01 22:23:13.661: WARN/System.err(628):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:553)
04-01 22:23:13.661: WARN/System.err(628):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:483)
04-01 22:23:13.672: WARN/System.err(628):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
04-01 22:23:13.672: WARN/System.err(628):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
```

This is my code

```
 url= new URL(queryString);         
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
PersonHandler myExampleHandler = new PersonHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

I am struking in two days. 
Any one can help me solve my problem..

XML Structure

```
<xml>
  <item>
    <queryType>compare-celebrity</queryType>
    <memberID>43</memberID>
    <memberName>Sachin</memberName>
    <memberSurname>Ramesh</memberSurname>
    <memberPersonalityType>[Red-Blue] Double</memberPersonalityType>
    <celebrityID>118</celebrityID>
    <celebrityName>Brad Pitt</celebrityName>
    <thumbnail>brad-pitt-1299831254.jpeg</thumbnail>
  </item>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [`xml` is not a valid element name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn).

> Names beginning with the string "`xml`", or with any string which would match `(('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l'))`, are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.

Use a different name for the root element:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <queryType>compare-celebrity</queryType>
    <memberID>43</memberID>
    <memberName>Sachin</memberName>
    <memberSurname>Ramesh</memberSurname>
    <memberPersonalityType>[Red-Blue] Double</memberPersonalityType>
    <celebrityID>118</celebrityID>
    <celebrityName>Brad Pitt</celebrityName>
    <thumbnail>brad-pitt-1299831254.jpeg</thumbnail>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: hi sorry, tis is my XML structure, tat time i was edited the post.

Comment: After changing the root element still i am receiving Parser Exception. Not all the time.